# VBScript Creating a Shortcut: Networked Folder for Current Logged-In user

Tags: vbscript, shortcut

I'm trying to create a shortcut to my user's desktop using VBScript. However, it seems that I'm missing something in my code, as it is trying to put the shortcut in the wrong directory, C:\desktop\My Scans instead of C:\Users\username\Desktop\My Scans.lnk

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sLinkFile = (desktopPath & "\My Scans.LNK")
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
oLink.Save
```

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks in adavnce for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Get the %userprofile% in a variable, or else it won't be recognized
userProfile = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%userprofile%" )
sLinkFile = userProfile & "\desktop\My Scans.LNK"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
oLink.Save
```

Comment: This worked, I was also able to set the target path. Thanks for you help jagsler!